# C - Recorrer arreglo bidimensional usando punteros

Tags: array, c, punteros

Tengo que imprimir los elementos de un arreglo de dos dimensiones:

```
int m[3][4]={{0,1,2,3},{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
```

Lo tengo que hacer usando estos punteros para acceder a los elementos del arreglo:

```
int *dos_ptr;
int(*ptr2vector)[4];
```

Mi problema es que no se donde inicializar los punteros que debo usar y tampoco entiendo como recorrer la matriz. Hasta ahora lo unico que he logrado es imprimir una de las "filas". Desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> Mi problema es que no se donde inicializar los punteros

En los bucles.

---

En general se aconseja que para bucles cuyo recorrido se desconoce (no sabes cuántas vueltas dará), se use `while` mientras que para bucles cuyo recorrido se conoce (sabes cuántas vueltas dará) se use `for`:

```
#define FILAS 3
#define COLUMNAS 4

for (int (*fila)[COLUMNAS] = m, (*fin)[COLUMNAS] = fila + FILAS; fila != fin; ++fila)
{
    for (int *valor = *fila, *fin = *fila + COLUMNAS; valor != fin; ++valor)
        printf("%d ", *valor);
    printf("\n");
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 
> 1 2 3 4 
> 5 6 7 8
> ```

Si te fijas inicializamos cuatro variables diferentes:

1. Primer bucle.

   1. `fila` apunta inicialmente al primer elemento de `m`.
   2. `fin` apunta a `fila` desplazado tres posiciones.
2. Segundo bucle.

   1. `valor` apunta inicialmente al primer valor de la `fila`.
   2. `fin` apunta a `valor` desplazado cuatro posiciones.

Fíjate que existen dos variables con el nombre `fin`, esto no supone un problema en C porque cada variable tiene su propio ámbito y las variables de ámbitos más bajos ocultan las de ámbitos superiores. Por lo que `fin` del primer bucle y `fin` del segundo bucle son diferentes.

---

Si el código anterior te parece complicado, podemos cambiar la notación de punteros a notación de índices:

```
#define FILAS 3
#define COLUMNAS 4

for (int fila = 0; fila != FILAS; ++fila)
{
    for (int columna = 0; columna != COLUMNAS; ++columna)
        printf("%d ", m[fila][columna]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

El código anterior produce el mismo resultado y las variables se inicializan en el mismo bucle.

---

Como alternativa, se puede hacer todo en un solo bucle:

```
#define FILAS 3
#define COLUMNAS 4

for (int indice = 0, fin = FILAS * COLUMNAS; indice != fin; ++indice)
{
    printf("%d ", m[indice / COLUMNAS][indice % COLUMNAS]);
    if (!((indice + 1) % COLUMNAS)) printf("\n");
}
```